# VS Code - find panel/view context name for shortcut 'when' expression

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm trying to add some shortcuts to my VS Code instance and I want to scope them using the `when` expression to avoid conflicts.

Alas, I'm struggling to find the right context name to use in the expression to achieve what I want.

I've searched the documentation and found that a number of them are listed here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_contexts

But, as the documentation says:

> The list above isn't exhaustive and you may see some when contexts for specific VS Code UI in the Default Keyboard Shortcuts.

Of course, the context to which I want to scope my shortcuts is not on the list ;)

Thus, **I was wondering if there was a way to find the context name of a specific panel/view in the VS Code UI.**

To illustrate this, suppose I'd like to make a shortcut active only when the panel that lists the available NPM scripts is focused... What context name should be used to achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried this - not expecting it to work - but it seems to:

```
"when": "focusedView == npm"
```

Similar info is [active/focussed view context clauses](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_activefocused-view-or-panel-when-clause-context).

In general, you can:

1. Open the developer tools: `Help/Toggle Developer Tools` and go to the console
2. Choose `Inspect Context Keys` in the VS Code Command Palette
3. Click on an element in the vscode window
4. Look in the tools console and expand the last item therein to show all the current context (when clauses).

But when I did that I didn't find anything helpful and `focusedView = ""`  was there, so that's not helpful.

so I just tried

```
{
  "key": "alt+i",
  "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
  "args": { "text": "howdy" },
  "when": "focusedView == npm"
},
```

that just prints `howdy` to the terminal for testing.. And the only way I could get it to work was when the `npm scripts` viewlet header or its contents had focus.

Comment: That's a start! I'll give this a try, then

Comment: Well... that's strange. I tried the procedure and was able to list all the context keys. Plus, `focusedView` was set to `npm`. But when I tried again later, clicking on the same panel yielded a `focusedView = ""`.

Comment: OK. Apparently, there's a little issue when poping up the Command Palette with `Ctrl+Shift+P` then selecting an option using the mouse or the `Enter` key. Doing so will lose the focus on the panel that was selected.
On the other hand, using the up & down arrow to move at least once then selecting the item with `Enter` will restore the focus to were it was.

Anyway, with the focus restored and `Inspect Context Keys` selected, clicking on the any panel will print the `focusedView` with the name of that panel.

Thanks mate!

Comment: How do you open `the tools console`?

Comment: Hello from the future! You can open the tools console by clicking "Help" and then "Toggle Developer Tools"

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to get to the change when expression dialogue (right click on the shortcut -> change when expression), and then use auto complete to find a possible when expression.

I just used this for the co-pilot chat when expression - I pressed ctrl+space then searched for chat and found it: inChatInput.